# Render Async Actions in a View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In our project we had only synchronous methods, so at a moment we decided to introduce some asynchronous ones.

But it seems there are some problems of using asynchronous actions in a view...

The bellow synchronous action "HomePartial" was transformed in an asynchronous "HomePartialAsync" one (so, no synchronous actions left).

The following code

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPortal.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-lg-19 col-md-18 col-sm-24 col-xs-24">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-24">
            <div class="row">
                @{Html.RenderAction<HomeController>(h => h.HomePartialAsync());}

                @Html.Partial("Partials/_OffersPassion")

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

throws actually an error

> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous
>   operation to complete.

My Home controller's action

```
[ActionName("HomePartial")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> HomePartialAsync()
{
    return WebConfigManager.IsCMSactivated ? await GetHomeManifCMSBlocAsync() : await GetHomeManifBlocAsync();
}
```

I updated it after the @JamesS suggestion like this

```
[ActionName("HomePartial")]
public ActionResult HomePartial()
{
    var asyncResult = WebConfigManager.IsCMSactivated ? GetHomeManifCMSBlocAsync() : GetHomeManifBlocAsync();
    var result = Task.Run(() => asyncResult).Result;
    return result;
}
```

but the thread appears to remain blocked expecting the "Result"....

Comment: You could call a sync action  and use `Task.Run(() => //async call).Result;` to call your async function

Comment: how to do it in the view?

Comment: I would say Just call a sync action and then in the controller action. Call an async function/ method using the syntax above. You can all the sync action much like you are in the `Html.Partial`

Comment: there is no sync action, the sync action became Async, I didn't keep the sync one

Comment: @JamesS `Task.Result` is a recipe for deadlock under asp.net. Please read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/08/28/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context/) if you don't understand why. `Task.Result` in general is toxic... here it's deadly.

Comment: @spender what would be your suggestion on how to do, rather on about how not to do?

Comment: @Serge this may be rooted deeper in the code. What does `GetHomeManifCMSBlocAsync` and `GetHomeManifBlocAsync` do? Check your code  to make sure you are not mixing any aync code with blocking code that can cause deadlocks. You are also using async/await on a call that does not need it.

Comment: Views don't support asynchronous code in ASP.NET Legacy Edition. ASP.NET Core views do, though.

Answer (score -2):

Personally I would call an `ActionResult` from the view and then call an async function from that.

View:

```
@Html.Partial("//HomePartial path")
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult HomePartial()
{
    var something = Task.Run(() => the call to the asynchronous function).Result;

    return PartialView("//partial path") //etc
}
```

Like I said personally this is what I would do however using this sort of method locks a thread until the async function is finished. This is fine if it is not being called often however if it is being called a lot, you might see issues appearing.

Comment: I need to replace the `@{Html.RenderAction<HomeController>(h => h.HomePartialAsync());}` with something...

Comment: Yes. If you simply replace it with `@html.Action()` OR `@Html.Partial()` and call the function like above, you can render the information

Comment: so you suggesting to rollback the asynchronous action to synchronous one? Because we just switched code from the synchronous to asynchronous... (see my controller's code in the updated OP)

Comment: @Serge It doesn't need to be for all. For example, if in that `Task.Run(() async => cal to whatever)` i suggested you call a partial and then in that partial you can call an async method and it should not cause any issues. However, I do not believe you can call an async function such as you have, like you have.

Comment: how do you link the "something" with the return?